# Centering a grid container

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
#panelb {
  background: lightblue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 300px);
}

.card {
  background: gold;
}

.imgcard {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='panelb'>
  <div class='card'>
    <img class='imgcard' src='imglink/01.jpg' alt='img'>
    <div class='linktitle'>TITLE</div>
  </div>

  <div class='card'>
    <img class='imgcard' src='imglink/02.jpg' alt='img'>
    <div class='linktitle'>TITLE</div>
  </div>

  ... and so on - about 50 cards
</div>
```

Everything works, except I want `panelb` always to be centered on page i.e. with dynamic width and equal left/right margins.

I cannot write `display:inline-block;` because it is already `display:grid`.

Also `margin: 0 auto` makes it width always 100% or another given width, regardless of number of `cards` in one row.

Any help?

Comment: This is not possible when using `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 300px);` as a width must be defined. *Otherwise, if the grid container has a definite minimal size in the relevant axis, the number of repetitions is the smallest possible positive integer that fulfills that minimum requirement. Otherwise, the specified track list repeats only once.*

Comment: @Paulie_D, I'd  suppose `grid` technology is invented to solve much more complex layout problems then centering a grid container.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the parent of the grid container a flex container, with centering properties.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

}
#panelb {
  flex: 1; /* tells grid container to take full width of flex container */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.card {
  background: gold;
}

.imgcard {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='panelb'>

  <div class='card'>
    <img class='imgcard' src='imglink/01.jpg' alt='img'>
    <div class='linktitle'>TITLE</div>
  </div>

  <div class='card'>
    <img class='imgcard' src='imglink/02.jpg' alt='img'>
    <div class='linktitle'>TITLE</div>
  </div>

  <div class='card'>
    <img class='imgcard' src='imglink/02.jpg' alt='img'>
    <div class='linktitle'>TITLE</div>
  </div>

  <div class='card'>
    <img class='imgcard' src='imglink/02.jpg' alt='img'>
    <div class='linktitle'>TITLE</div>
  </div>

  <div class='card'>
    <img class='imgcard' src='imglink/02.jpg' alt='img'>
    <div class='linktitle'>TITLE</div>
  </div>

  <div class='card'>
    <img class='imgcard' src='imglink/02.jpg' alt='img'>
    <div class='linktitle'>TITLE</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jrvx6hev/)

Comment: I cannot have `body - display:flex` because of other elements on  page.

Comment: It's a concept based on the code in your question. In reality, you would make the parent of `#panelb`, whatever it may be, the flex container.